# How can I get DevOps build agent to wipe a pipeline's directory pre-build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

A DevOps pipeline I created chooses folder `b:\DevOpsBuilds\_work\1` to perform the build. However it doesn't remove this folder each run.

Is there a way to force it to, so each build is completely from scratch?

When I create a new pipeline, there are no settings relating to cleaning:

[image]

Comment: Do you specifically want it to clean up after the build, or would you be ok with it happening before, maybe using the workspace options?
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all

Comment: @EggyBach it's _before_ I am interested in. I actually prefer the build is left afterwards (until next run) so I can inspect it if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get DEvOps build agent to wipe a pipeline's directory pre-build?

If you want to delete the folder `b:\DevOpsBuilds\_work\1` pre-build, I am afraid it is impossible to do it automated.

As workaround, you could use the **Clean** option on the Get Source tab, which could perform different kinds of cleaning of the working directory of your private agent before the build is run:

[image]

We could set the value to `true` to clean the working directory of your private agent. You could select the **All build directories** to clean all folder for the path `b:\DevOpsBuilds\_work\1`

You could check the document [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent) for some more details.

Comment: Can I edit this setting _after_ creating the pipeline? I have found before some settings seem to be impossible to find alter!

Comment: @Mr.Boy, Yes, you can edit it at any time.

Comment: I do not have those options. And when I go to edit an existing pipeline, I cannot see anything like this.

Comment: @Mr.Boy, oddly, would you please give me a image when you edit the pipeline and click the get sources in your question?